# How to ask Roslyn to generate an identifier name for me?

Tags: roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

As the title says, how do I ask Roslyn to generate an identifier for me, similar to how the pattern matching code fixer or the generate method ones do?

[image]

Comment: How to ask ? Politely ! :)
The "getHashCode()" does not really generate an identifier ; it "tries" to generate a pseudo-code based on "value" of the object (this last sentence may initiate a lot of debates).
To answer, we may need to know what you are trying to achieve exactly.

Comment: I'm talking specifically about `document1` which is generated by Roslyn based on the type being matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there is an internal class inside Roslyn that does this, but it does much more than what I need.

Instead, I simply used the semantic model to get the list of visible symbols at the start of my block's span, named my identifier the same as my type (just starting with a lowercase letter) and started adding numbers at the end of it until I get something that's not otherwise visible:

```
        var symbols = new HashSet<string>(semanticModel.LookupSymbols(bes.SpanStart).Select(s => s.Name));

        var baseIdentifierName = baseType is PredefinedTypeSyntax pts ? pts.Keyword.ValueText : throw new InvalidOperationException();
        if (isArray && !baseIdentifierName.EndsWith("s"))
            baseIdentifierName += "s";
        if (char.IsUpper(baseIdentifierName[0]))
            baseIdentifierName = $"{char.ToLower(baseIdentifierName[0])}{baseIdentifierName.Substring(1)}";

        var identifierName = baseIdentifierName;
        var index = 0;
        while (symbols.Contains(identifierName))
            identifierName = baseIdentifierName + ++index;
```